# How can I Avoid repeating similar expressions?

Tags: haskell

I have a function that reduces a binary tree to a list of node values in a given order (infix, prefix, postfix and inversed infix, prefix, postfix). The code below works, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do it without repeating the function implementation 6 times with just a different order of arguments:

```
data DOrd  = Infix | Praefix | Postfix | GInfix | GPraefix | GPostfix
data BTree =    Nil | BNode Int BTree BTree deriving (Eq,Ord,Show)

flatten :: BTree -> DOrd -> [Int]
flatten Nil             _       = []
flatten (BNode n b1 b2) Infix   = flatten b1 Infix ++ [n] ++ flatten b2 Infix
flatten (BNode n b1 b2) Praefix = [n] ++ flatten b1 Praefix ++ flatten b2 Praefix
---6 times basically the same for all the elements in DOrd
```

I thought about functionals or extending DOrd from basically an enum to a more sophisticated structure - but I couldn't figure out how.

Comment: TU Vienna? ;-) Did it myself yesterday.

Comment: @Mike: yes :) I also asked the tutor today, he didn't know a nicer solution either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have no clue what the G versions are for.  But this would work to factor out the commonality in the three I understand:

```
data DOrd = Infix | Praefix | Postfix | GInfix | GPraefix | GPostfix
data BTree =    Nil | BNode Int BTree BTree deriving (Eq,Ord,Show)

flatten :: BTree -> DOrd -> [Int]
flatten Nil _ = []
flatten (BNode n b1 b2) ord = case ord of
    Praefix -> c ++ l ++ r
    Infix   -> l ++ c ++ r
    Postfix -> l ++ r ++ c
    ...
  where
    l = flatten b1 ord -- left
    r = flatten b2 ord -- right
    c = [n]            -- current
```

This is simply factoring the parts of the code that are the same in all the cases into short names which don't obscure the logic for the parts that do vary depending on the DOrd value.

Comment: GInfix is just Infix reversed = r->c->l

Comment: @mort Where does that naming come from?  It's not a convention I'm familiar with.

Comment: From the assignment. It's just playing around; the 'G' stands for the German "Gespielte Variante" which means "a variant just for playing around"

Comment: I accepted this answer because in terms of readability and avoiding copy-paste this one seems to be the best to me. Apart from that, it's also quite simple.

Answer (score 5):

I think defining a fold function for your data structure would be useful here to separate out the concern of recursing over the structure, and it would likely be reusable elsewhere in your code:

```
fold :: (Int -> a -> a -> a) -> a -> BTree -> a
fold _ x Nil = x
fold f x (BNode n b1 b2) = f n (fold f x b1) (fold f x b2)
```

Now, you can easily write `flatten` in terms of `fold` and `reorder` (inspired by dave4420's answer):

```
flatten :: DOrd -> BTree -> [Int]
flatten order = fold f []
  where f n b1 b2 = mconcat $ reorder order [n] b1 b2

reorder Praefix a b c = [a, b, c]
reorder Infix   a b c = [b, a, c]
...
```

Note that I took the liberty of changing the order of the arguments to `flatten`. Having the data structure as the last argument makes it easier to use with partial application, and it also makes the definition neater.

Answer (score 4):

Separate the reordering into its own function.

```
flatten :: BTree -> DOrd -> [Int]
flatten Nil _ = []
flatten (BNode n b1 b2) order = reorder order (flatten b1 order) [n] (flatten b2 order)

reorder :: Monoid m => DOrd -> m -> m -> m -> m
reorder Infix    a b c = mconcat [a, b, c]
reorder Praefix  a b c = mconcat [b, a, c]
reorder Postfix  a b c = mconcat [a, c, b]
reorder GInfix   a b c = mconcat [c, b, a]
reorder GPraefix a b c = mconcat [c, a, b]
reorder GPostfix a b c = mconcat [b, c, a]
```

Your original code only needs it to work for lists, but this will work for all monoids.